# Colorbox demonstration all the same?

Tags: colorbox

On http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ there is a **View Demonstration** box on the left.  But when I click on any of the examples 1-5 it looks the same.

All of them have **Elastic Transition**, **Fade Transition**, etc.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different demos illustrate 5 different colorbox styles (UIs).  All of the galleries are the same amongst the five.
Download the plugin and see the five different folders.